# Default for <%# (bind or eval)

Tags: c#, asp.net

For something like this:

```
<asp:panel id="pnl_ItemOrder" runat="server" cssclass="ItemOrder" visible="<%# CheckEdit_Status(IsEditable) %>">
```

How do I know if it's using Bind or Eval? Or what is it doing?

Comment: Bind is both ways, Eval is one way...

Comment: @leppie I know that but does <%# %> = (<%# BIND() %> or  <%#EVAL()%>)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay since it was about 5 years since I worked on anything closely related to webforms, this is going to be a estimation of what happens:

```
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<script type="text/C#" runat="server">
    private const bool isEdit = true;
</script>
<script type="text/C#" runat="server">

    private bool CheckEdit_Status(bool isEdit)
    {
        return isEdit;
    }

</script>
<asp:Panel ID="pnl_ItemOrder" runat="server" Visible="<%# (CheckEdit_Status(isEdit)) %>"
    Height="100" Width="100" BackColor="Aqua">
</asp:Panel>
<br />
<% pnl_ItemOrder.DataBind(); %>
</form>
```

This is what I played around with and from my logical reasoning and the few things I do remember from school the <%# %> tag is more often used to call functions, eval is used for evaluating object and casts it to a string for representation in things such as repeaters and datagrids, which use arrays of values.

Eval, is used to fetch an item an from the databinder and present it in it's respective databound (this is important) controller, here you call a function which doesn't need to have any representation on the page and is not in a databound controller but instead set on a panel, so instead you tell the server to set this flag for me.

Switching to Eval will cause a exception to be thrown that we can't cast a bool to a string, since there's no way of representing a bool as a string (yes there's the ability to call the object.ToString() method on it but that's not really the same thing and it will throw an exception in this case since visible is a boolean not a string value).

Bind is an old obsolete version of Eval mainly used for backwards compability, if I understood it correctly.

TLDR;

It's neither it's just there to tell the server to call a function and what ever the server gets back = set that value here.

Comment: You could have just typed the last sentence.

Answer (score 3):

What it is doing is calling a function named **CheckEdit_Status()**.

Take a look at the code behind file for that method and property. If Bind() or Eval() is being used it will be in that method, or some method called by it.